# Proving for all x there is a y such that Q

Tags: proof-writing

The specific problem I have is $\forall x\in[0,1), \exists y\in[0,1) \ $ such that $ x<y$. But I think this can be generalized to for all x, there is a y such that Q, where Q is a statement like x

So how would I approach this? I think y needs to be expressed as a limit when y approaches 1. Unfortunately, I do not know how to express this.

Going back to the "generalized" form, what would be the way to approach such a problem? What I mean is if, instead, we have $\exists y\in[0,1), \forall x\in[0,1)\ $, we would just pick a y and easily prove x, so is there some sort of strategy like this for this form?

Comment: Generally, $\forall x\exists y$ is less restrictive than $\exists y\forall x$. For the continuation $\ldots x<y$, one is true and the other isn't (at least when $x,y\in[0,1)$).

Comment: What do you mean by less restrictive? Any articles I can read? ELI5?

Comment: What actually is this $Q$? You introduce in a sentence without an ending.

Comment: 1)$\forall x\exists y$ means that for any $x$ you must find *a* $y$ that works for that *single* particular $x$.  2)$\exists y\forall x$ means you must find a $y$ then works for *every* possible $x$.  Since for 1) you must only find an $y$ for a specific $x$ and in 2) you must find a $y$ for every *possible* $x$ 1) is "less restrictive"  (and *much* easier to prove).  Consider $Q$ is $x =y$.  For all $x$ there is a $y$ so that $x = y$ (that's obviously true; just let $y = x$). There exists a $y$ so that for all $x$ then $x = y$ is obviously false. There's no $y$ that is equal to *everything*.

Comment: I see; I based my assumption on $\exists y \in \mathbb R$ s.t $\forall \in [0,2], x^2+1<y$. In this case, I just picked a very large y. For $\forall x \exists y$, you still need to make x a generic x right? You can't just pick a number, so that means y will likely be an expression right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\forall x\in[0,1), \exists y\in[0,1) \ $ such that $ x<y$

Hint:   prove that $\, x \lt (x+1)/2 \lt 1\,$ for $\,\forall x\in[0,1)\,$. Intuition here is that $\,(x+1)/2\,$ is the midpoint between $\,x\,$ and $\,1\,$.

> if, instead, we have $\exists y\in[0,1), \forall x\in[0,1)\ $

That does not hold true, consider for example $\,x=(y+1)/2\,$.

Comment: So for $\forall x \in [a,b], \exists y \in [a,b]$ you want to find a formula for y that satisfies the condition Q, e.g, x < y?

Comment: How do I prove the midpoint?

Comment: @user2793618 `So for ∀x∈[a,b] ...`  No, note that the interval $[0,1)$ is *open* at the right end. That is essential here, otherwise the statement would no longer hold true if you replaced $[0,1)$ with the closed interval $[0,1]$. Think about $x=1$ for example. `How do I prove the midpoint` One way is to start with $x \lt 1$, then the distance between $x$ and $1$ is $1-x$ and the midpoint is the left end plus half the distance i.e. $x + (1-x)/2 = (x+1)/2\,$.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. The question was just about in general if you have an universal quantifier binding x followed by a existential quantifier for y, you want to find a formula for y right?

Comment: @user2793618 Proving something like $\exists y$ doesn't always require finding a formula for $y$, but if you are able to find one then that's always sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards.

$\forall x, \exists Y$ is is usually much easier to prove and you do it by simply " just pick a $y$" and showing it exist.

For instance if $Q$ is $x <y $ then just "pick" $y; x < y < 1$... say $y = \frac {1+x}2$.

Or if for instance $Q$ is $x = y$ then just "pick" $y = x$.

$\exists Y \forall x$ is much *harder* to prove because you must pick a $y$ that is true for *ALL* $x$ and not just a single $x$.

If $Q$ is $x < y$ then you *can't* prove $\exists Y \in [0,1)\forall x \in [0,1)$ because it simply is not true!  For *any* $y$ that you pick, then there will always be an $x; y < x < 1$ and it will *NOT* be true that $x < y$.

And if $Q$ is $x =y$ that is especially clear that $\exists y\forall x$ that $x = y$.  For $x = \frac 14$ and for $x = \frac 12$ there is no possible $y$ so that $y$ is equal to *both* $\frac 14$ and $\frac 12$.

Comment: So while you pick a single x for the universal quantifier, you will likely need to express y in terms of a formula/expression right (x needs to represent all x)?